# Screen width is not accurate. Becomes accurate if scrollbar is removed

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming

I'm redesigning my website and all of a sudden, the screen width is not being shown as accurate. I have a MacBook Pro mid 2015 and the screen width is 1440x900. I have jQuery script that tells me the screen width of the my website, which is suppose to be 1440px wide. This morning when I booted up my site, the jQuery script shows my site as 1425px wide. It returns to normal when I hide the scrollbars on the browser. This also occurs in Chrome.

http://wpfreelance.bayoumedia.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in jquery to get actual screen width, without the scroll bar.

```
var actualInnerWidth = $("body").prop("scrollWidth");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).width()` should show the actual width of the window, which should match 1440px wheter there's a scrollbar present or not.

`$("body").prop("scrollWidth")` will match the width excluding the scroll bars (if present). So guess this is the one you're using